# Does it make sense to use composite pattern in tree view?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, composite

I have a tree view where every node is a different type of item - only the label and description property is the same. Does it make sense to represent each of these node item by composite component?

One of the reason I ask is that I have noticed while applying composite design pattern makes it easier to apply aggregate function (applied to aggregate object), it gets somewhat harder to actually access individual items inside that aggregate.

This usually means to access the individual item, it will require type casting the item back to its original type or it needs to contain the type information which is considered a bad practice in OOP. These inner objects are not really exposed anyways in common examples.

To put this in perspective, consider I have TreeView which shows tourist attraction in 3 major cities. The first level of node is the city name, which than contains attractions in that city.

```
New York
   Time Square
   Central Park
London
   British Meuseum
Paris
   Eiffel Tower
```

So now when user clicks on city, the program displays information about that city (say in right pane), if they click the attraction, it shows information on that attraction.

Is this a fit for composite design pattern? if so wouldn't it require typecasting the component back to what exactly it is like city or attraction?

Secondly wouldn't that require digging out the component out of the composite to be able to display it? Kind of against the pattern which tends to put them together?

If it matters, my environment is C++/Qt.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Short Answer**

No, you don't have to use the "Composite" Software Design Pattern, you can declare each item with its own specific class / type.

**Long Boring Extended Answer**

You don't.

Collections, like stacks, lists, matrices (plural for matrix), and specially tree-like collections are a natural way to use this pattern, where all items are of the same class or type, or can behave as if they have the same class, type or interface, even if they have a different type.

Yet, in many cases is preferrable to use it, and declare all items with the same type, like the same super class or same interface,
because it allows to perform common operations, to all elements.

You may find that several GUI interfaces and controls like QT,
apply this pattern to elements that are not exactly the same class,
just because they need to print each element's image or label.

Casting backward or forward from the general class to the specific class,
(also known as "variance" and "contravariance"), in each item,
can be complex, but, can be useful in a logn term programming.

Note: The same applies, if you use prototypes, or interface inheritance,
instead of class inheritance, to implement this pattern.

**Summary**

Software Design Patterns and Best Practices, are guidelines, not strict rules, it means they can be helpful in some situations, and not so helpful  in other scenarios.

You may explicitly avoid using them,
if you rationally believe it doesn't suit your needs.